# Hide virtual keyboard always

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Actually i have a edit text.when i click edit text virtual keyboard popups.But i just wanna hide virtual keyboard always even after click on edit text.And edit text should be printable with system keyboard.How could i do this?
My code..

```
EditText edtNote = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.note);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.restartInput(edtNote);

Configuration config = this.getResources().getConfiguration();

if (config.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}
```

Comment: Did you try EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

Comment: where should i insert that code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try edtNote.setInputType(InputType.Type_Null); it has advantages and disadvantage.
Android wont treat the element as an input element. You cant enter anything after this